# Script to modify a URL in greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

I'm trying to change the following url:

```
http://www.example.net/?image=full&action=view&imageid=1361
```

into

```
http://www.anothersite.com/download&id=1361&thumb=0
```

while preserving the id (`1361` in the example)

(change 'example.net/?image=full&action=view&image' to 'anothersite.com/download&' and add '&thumb=0' at the end of the url)

How do I write a GreaseMonkey script for that?

---

ps. I've already googled it and copied the code below. It's working, but the problem is it adds '&thumb=0' to the other link too (not just the 'replaced' link(s))

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        whatever
// @namespace   lii
// @description redirect to anothersite
// @include     http://www.example.net/?image=full&action=view*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var links,thisLink;
links = document.evaluate("//a[@href]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);

for (var i=0;i<links.snapshotLength;i++) {
    var thisLink = links.snapshotItem(i);

    thisLink.href = thisLink.href.replace('http://www.example.net/?image=full&action=view&image',
                                          'http://www.anothersite.com/download&')  + "&thumb=0";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
thisLink.href = thisLink.href.replace(RegExp('http://www\\.example\\.net/\\?image=full&action=view&image(.*)'),
                                      'http://www.anothersite.com/download&$1&thumb=0');
```

It applies regular expression to match the URL and extract the id and inserts it as `$1` into the resulting string.

More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).