# Greasemonkey script to change all links that match to a different domain

Tags: javascript, youtube, greasemonkey

I need a greasemonkey script that will replace all instances of youtube.com and youtu.be with hooktube.com and keep the watch?v=vidID intact. I've tried modifying other examples on stackoverflow but they are more complex than what I need and I know next to nothing about javascript. I've been trying to modify this one: [Script to modify a URL in greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540877/script-to-modify-a-url-in-greasemonkey) but I can't get it to do anything and I have no idea how to debug it.

Comment: I've actually got something that is almost working. Will update when I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick. Hope it can help someone in the future...

```
var links,thisLink;
links = document.evaluate("//a[@href]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);

for (var i=0;i<links.snapshotLength;i++) {
    var thisLink = links.snapshotItem(i);

  thisLink.href = thisLink.href.replace(RegExp('https?://www\\.youtube\\.com/(.*)'),
                                      'https://www\.hooktube\.com/$1');

  thisLink.href = thisLink.href.replace(RegExp('https?://youtu\\.be/(.*)'),
                                      'https://www\.hooktube\.com/watch\?v=$1');
}
```

Thanks to [Script to modify a URL in greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540877/script-to-modify-a-url-in-greasemonkey)

Comment: How do I put this in Greasemonkey?